# Override the else part of the index.php loop.

Tags: archive-template

How do you prevent the else statement of the themes index.php from running in a custom archive page template.

For example the default theme has:

```
// If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
else :
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

endif;
```

I have tried:

```
else : ?>

nothing here dude!

<?php endif; ?>
```

However it still loads the template part for no content. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: may be you don't edit the good file. try a plugin like "Query Monitor" to find which file is used in the theme : https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Comment: It's loading archive.php when my custom taxonomy archive is empty.

Comment: Then you need to modify archive.php

Comment: @Jacob Peattie - that isn't helpful. I am trying to avoid loading archive.php when my custom post type is empty. I would like to display a different page to what the standard posts show.